# echo 'the character - (dash) in the unix command line

Tags: linux, echo

This is an extremely simple question that had absolutely nothing related on the internet no matter what. 
How do I print a single dash with the echo command? I tried escaping it with '\', '/', '-', '%' and even '#', but it seemed it refused to print a simple, single dash character nonetheless. I tried it with a single quote, double quote or no quote at all, but it seems that this simply isn't possible with echo. Nothing on the man page nor anywhere else, for that matter, can someone please tell me how to do this?
To make things absolutely clear: I want to use echo '-' (or anything like this ) and get a single dash - as output

Comment: `echo -` works on my system.

Comment: works fine with xterm (unquoted), what terminal are you using?

Comment: for me it prints simply the newline character, I'm trying to use this to print a minus sign on my terminal, but it's not really working (I use a debian derivative linux with urxvt btw) EDIT: I tried with both xterm and termite, but no luck

Comment: Try `printf -- "-\n"` (you need the `--` to indicate end of options)

Comment: printf was working before, my problem was with echo. Funny thing is that using "echo -n "-\n" works the same way. It might not be the most optimal solution, but at least it's a solution EDIT: Well, problem is that it still prints a new line, and I kinda needed it in the same line (-n only removes one new line)

Comment: Works fine here. What shell are you using?

Comment: zsh with oh -my-zsh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question was asked more than 2 years ago, but I've just noticed that `echo` on bash and zsh behaves differently.

On Zsh, the first dash is used to terminate option processing; so as @asatsi answered, you can print `-` with

```sh
% echo - -
-
```

On Bash, single dash works just fine.

```sh
$ echo -
-
```

From The Z Shell Manual (http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html)

> echo [ -neE ] [ arg ... ]
>
> ...
>
> Note that for standards compliance a double dash does not terminate option processing; instead, it is printed directly. However, a single dash does terminate option processing, so the first dash, possibly following options, is not printed, but everything following it is printed as an argument. The single dash behaviour is different from other shells. For a more portable way of printing text, see printf, and for a more controllable way of printing text within zsh, see print.

Answer (score 2):

Try this on zsh:

```
[asatsi@stevevai]~% echo - -
-
```

Comment: This actually worked. I had to use echo - '-' in order to print it right, because it was inside of a script, but I honestly don't understand why has this worked.. Does echo interpret the first dash as some sort of command?

Answer (score 0):

echo - works on my system.
Linux and bash.

[image: echo - in bash]

Comment: I've tested with bash and sh and it worked just fine, it's probably a problem with zsh then. Anyone has any ideas of how to fix this?