# How to echo bare hypen (`-`) in zsh?

Tags: echo, zsh

I'm looking for a way to work around zsh echo's apparently treating a string that is just a hyphen as if it were an empty string

```sh
echo -
# no output

echo "-"
# no output

echo '-'
# no output
```

Specifically, I'm splitting a string at a known character and then working with the two pieces, and either of the two pieces could be `-`. Like

```sh
% my_f() {
  my_arr=(${(s.b.)1})
  echo $my_arr[1]
  echo $my_arr[2]
}

% my_f "abc"
a
b

% my_f "-bc"
# I need to know -
b

% my_f "ab-"
a
# I need to know -

%
```

In the particular thing I'm working on, I can rework things so that the potential `-` isn't echo'd on its own

```sh
my_arr=(${(qqqs.b.)1})
echo " ${(Q)my_arr[1]} "
echo " ${(Q)my_arr[2]} "
```

But that feels like luck and will take sprinkling a lot of `qqq` and `Q` around this script. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `echo - "-"`. The first dash terminates option processing, so following text is printed.

See this excellent answer for more context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57656708/11776945

Comment: Aha that explains it!

Answer (score 1):

Use `printf` instead. (Which is generally good advice regarding *any* use of `echo`.)

```
my_f () {
  printf '%s\n' "${(s.b.)1}"
}
```

Comment: Fair, I was caught up in being surprised about `echo`'s behavior