# How to reassign a variable (zsh) when using source utility

Tags: macos, shell, zsh

The code below tests if the character from a string is matching regex or not.

```
str=")Y"
c="${str:0:1}"
if [[ $c =~ [A-Za-z0-9_] ]]; then
    echo "YES"
    output=$c
else
    echo "NO"
    output="-"
fi
echo $output
```

I am running it with

```
source script-name.sh
```

However, instead of expected printout

```
NO
-
```

I am getting an empty line without dash

```
NO
```

I understand the issue is somehow around the way i (re-)assign output variable which being me to questions

1. How to do it properly?
2. Why source utility has such implication?

UPD_1: it is for Mac's zsh, not bash
UPD_2: the issue occurs only when running script via 'source' utility like "source script-name.sh"

Running with "./script-name.sh" yield correct result as well.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention - its in Mac's zsh. Indeed, when switching to bash it works.. I will update the description

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code gives the expected output for bash 4.2.46 on RHEL7.
Are you maybe using zsh?

See [echo 'the character - (dash) in the unix command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448096/echo-the-character-dash-in-the-unix-command-line)

EDIT: Ok, if it's zsh, you probably have to use a hack:

```
if [[ ${output} == '-' ]]; then
    echo - ${output}
else
    echo ${output}
fi
```

or use printf:

```
printf  $output"\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be simplified to do on the zsh command line a

```
echo -
```

which also doesn't output anything. Similarily, a

```
echo - x
```

would output simply *x* and not `- x`.

This does not depend on whether or not you are on the Mac. If you would do a

```
echo - -
```

or a

```
=echo -
```

(the latter using the external program `echo`) would print a dash.

Therefore, you can change in your `script-name.sh` a

```
=echo $output
```

or a

```
echo - $output
```

and you should be fine.

The *zshbuiltins* man-page explains it, when describing the `echo` command:

> the first dash, possibly following options, is not printed, but everything  following  it  is  printed  as an argument.

Therefore, in zsh, at least when printing a variable, it is better to also use a lone dash for the safe side.

Comment: Both, =echo and echo - $output are zsh-specific which is why I'd not recommend using them, at least if you want the script to work in bash too.